# How do I set up panning in a viewport?

Tags: screen, xubuntu

I am trying to make my desktop larger than my screen, thus making my screen a "viewport". When I run:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1280x800 --fb 1600x1600 --panning 800x600
```

My desktop increases in size when I run this command, but my screen does not pan when I move the mouse to the edge

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the default window manager in ubuntu 11.10 is compiz and that it doesnt support panning viewports.  Because its interaction model is tied to workspaces and switching between them I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your panning area is smaller than the actual physical screen.
Try something like:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1280x800 --fb 1600x1600 --panning 1600x1600
```